# Form submition with jQuery is not working correctly with IE8

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, browser, form-submit

jQuery `$.ajax()` does not seem to work correctly with IE8 but it is working with Firefox, Chrome and Safari. I am submittin the form and response back in **JSON** format.

### Here is my code:

**test.php:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jsFile.js"></script>

<form action='_test.php' method='post' class='ajaxform'>
 <input type='text' name='txt' value='Test Text'>
 <input type='submit' value='submit'>
</form>

<div id='testDiv'></div>
```

**_test.php:**

```
<?php
      $arr = array( 'testDiv' => $_POST['txt'] );
      echo json_encode( $arr );
?>
```

**jsFile.js:**

```
jQuery('.ajaxform').live('submit', function(event) {

 $.ajax({
        url  : $(this).attr('action'),
        type : $(this).attr('method'),
        dataType: 'json',
        data : $(this).serialize(),
        success : function( data ) {
     for(var id in data) {
      jQuery('#' + id).html( data[id] );
     }
            }
    });

 return false;
});
```

### Behavior:

**In Firefox, Chrome, Safari:**

When I submit the form then value of **textfield(txt)** is successfully populated in **DIV(testDiv)** without disturbing whole page.

**In IE:**

When I submit the form then it just shows json form on screen like this: `{"testDiv":"Test Text"}`

How to solve this problem in IE?

Thanks.

Comment: Try putting `alert(typeof(data)+': '+data);` at the top of your `success` handler. what does it show?

Comment: @aularon: In IE it shows same result(`{"testDiv";"Test Text"}`) BUT in other browsers it shows `object: [object Object]` in alert box. It means it is not going in success function in IE.

Comment: Oh. Solved my issue. Please check my posted answer. Thanks to all to help me solving my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I replaced my jquery code with this and it is working on all browsers:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery('.ajaxform').submit( function() {

        $.ajax({
            url     : $(this).attr('action'),
            type    : $(this).attr('method'),
            dataType: 'json',
            data    : $(this).serialize(),
            success : function( data ) {
                        for(var id in data) {
                            jQuery('#' + id).html( data[id] );
                        }
                      }
        });

        return false;
    });

});
```

I don't know what is this but it is working now. Thanks to all to participate and help me to solve this issues.

Comment: LOL! I forgot to asked if you wrapped it in the ready handler... +1 for figuring it out yourself ;)

Comment: I think it's the change to using the `submit` callback rather than wrapping in `ready` that fixed it - I think previously it was just doing a normal submit, i.e. selector not working.

Comment: @sje397: Combination of **'wrapping in ready'** and **submit()** solved the issue. When I only use submit() without wrapping it in ready() it does not work on any browser. And when I use `jQuery('.ajaxform').live('submit', function(event) {}` in ready() or not in ready() it does not work with IE only.

Comment: What I mean is, using the `submit` callback makes the javascript work - previously I think it wasn't being applied at all and normal form submission was happening. Moving the script to the bottom of the page, using the `submit` callback, and not using `ready` would probably have the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

instead of

```
for(var id in data) {
  jQuery('#' + id).html( data[id] );
}
```

have you tried using [`$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) ?

```
jQuery.each(data , function(id, val) {
  jQuery('#' + id).html( val );
});
```

and also, you have misinterpret `$(this)`,  (*I guess*)

```
jQuery('.ajaxform').live('submit', function(event) {

  var $this = $(this); // add this line...

 $.ajax({
        url  : $this.attr('action'),
        type : $this.attr('method'),
        dataType: 'json',
        data : $this.serialize(),
        success : function( data ) {
     for(var id in data) {
      jQuery('#' + id).html( data[id] );
     }
            }
    });

 return false;
});
```

Comment: same result when I use `var $this = $(this);`

Comment: my mistake, in `Query.each(data , function(i, val) {`. the `i` should be `id` like this `function(id, val)`. please try.

Answer (score 1):

<s>Your JSON response (output of `_test.php`) should contain `:` instead of `;`, as @sje397 said. Seems like other browser are okay with `;`, but not IE8, so the value is kept a string instead being parsed as an object.</s>

**EDIT:** for some reason your data isn't being converted to json, try putting

```
if(typeof(data)=='string') {
  data=$.parseJSON(data);
}
```

at the top of your `success` handler and see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

FYI:

Naveed, I tried the code you posted in IE8 on Win 7 (both in Compatibility and non-Compatibility modes) and it displayed the 'Test Text' correctly as plain text inside the div and not in JSON format.

Comment: Strange! I am also checking it in IE8 on Win7 but it is showing json format. Which jquery version are you using.

Comment: 1.4.2.min.js from Google CDN. PHP 5.2.8 running on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

1. Try changing the selector (to `input:submit` or `:submit`)
2. Add an error handler to the ajax call and see what it says

Comment: Ok. You are right. Accepted answer helps to figure out the solution easily in future. Thanks.